# how do I Iterate through a group of records in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, datasource

I have a crystal report within a crystal report viewer that the datasource is set to a `List<objects>`. The crystal report is showing all of the records, my question is how do I set the report to only show the first record and then I can allow the user to iterate through each of the `List<objects>` on at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself. I had to use custom buttons to manually load in each data record and refresh the report.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the Detail section (assumedly where you have the fields placed) and select 'Section Expert...'.  Choose 'New Page After'.  Each row in the Detail section will on a separate page.  The user can use the cursor buttons (First, Previous, Next, Last) to move between each page--the buttons resemble those on a DVD player.